# flash for ubuntu mate 16.04 on 32 bit system

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, mate, ubuntu-mate

How can I setup flash to work on chromium and or mozilla on ubuntu mate 16.04 on a 32 bit system?  I've been researching and trying several options but nothing seems to work.  I also came to find out that apparently you can't install chrome and 32 bit system anymore and have to use chromium, so installing chrome and updating is not an option I guess.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just install flash?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html (It should apply to Ubuntu MATE as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I already had adobe flash player installed but it still wasn't working for mozilla or chremium.  I looked again in the software center and saw that Pepper Flash Player was not installed.  Installing pepper flash seems to have addressed the issue.  However, for some reason I still can't get vidoes from nbc live to play.  They just show "coverage concluded".  I'm not getting the message that flash is not installed however, so I'll just have to play around with this. Thanks.